# Pass an Output Value into a Data Block

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, vpc-endpoint

I'd like to pass an output value into a data block but don't know how

```
output "vpce_interface_ids" {
  value = join(",", aws_vpc_endpoint.vpce.network_interface_ids)
}

data "aws_network_interface" "ENI_0" {
  id = ""
}
```

Comment: Why would you ever need to pass an output into a data block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to do that.

If your scope is to pass `join(",",aws_vpc_endpoint.vpce.network_interface_ids)` as `id` in datasource you can use a local block or pass it directly

#### Option 1

```
locals {
  id = join(",", aws_vpc_endpoint.vpce.network_interface_ids)
}

data "aws_network_interface" "ENI_0" {
  id = local.id
}
```

#### Option 2

```
data "aws_network_interface" "ENI_0" {
  id = join(",", aws_vpc_endpoint.vpce.network_interface_ids)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize the locals block can be used this way.